# bootstrap navbar not responsive when sliding to mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

i don't get why my bootstrap navbar is not responsive. its scaling to a mini navbar when i slide.
i did a gif to show what i mean.[image]

this is the simple code with no added extra CSS
It is not scaling like a normal navbar would to when it is responsive, this one here drives me crazy and i dont know why it wont work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Frontend Task - Landingpage</title>
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:500&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav
      class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span
                class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"
              role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
              aria-expanded="false"> Dropdown </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1"
              aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search"
            aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0"
            type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="jumbotron-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-4 w-50">Always Look On The Bright Side Of Life</h1>
        <p class="lead">In efforts to expand our horizons, we welcome every
          investment-minded individual to join us in the Condotel Investment
          Opportunity.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
      </div>
    </div> -->
  <!-- SCRIPTS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script
    src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add ``<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`` inside ``<head>`` tag and check if it works.

Comment: life saver, thank you

Comment: Need the meta viewport tag like https://codeply.com/p/HcFLgvGkYi